# Get list of objects with unique combination of id/values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this collection:

```
{
  Id: 5,
  postalcodes: {2000, 3000, 4000}
}, 
{
 Id: 5,
 postalcodes: { 2000, 5000 }
},
{
 Id: 6,
 postalcodes: { 2000, 7000 }
}
```

I would like to get a list of objects containing an ID and postalcode. The ID may occur multiple times, but the postalcode should be unique PER id.

So my result would be:

```
{
 id: 5,
 postalcode: 2000
}
{
 id: 5,
 postalcode: 3000
}
{ 
 id: 5,
 postalcode: 4000
}
{
 id: 5,
 postalcode: 5000
}
{
 id: 6,
 postalcode: 2000
}
{
 id: 6,
 postalcode: 7000
}
```

This is my query:

```
collection.Select(x => new

                                                                 {
                                                                     x.id,
                                                                     x.postalcodes
                                                                 })
    .Distinct()
```

I'm stuck in how to flatten the postalcodes so each postal code would create a seperate object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
var pairs = collection.SelectMany(x => x.postalcodes.Select(
        y => new { x.Id, postalcode = y })).Distinct();

foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Id}, {pair.postalcode}");
}
```

Or in LINQ *language* terms:

```
var pairs = (from x in collection
             from postalcode in x.postalcodes
             select new { x.Id, postalcode }).Distinct();
```

The `SelectMany` expands an inner collection, giving us all the `Id` / `postalcode` pairs; then the `Distinct` collapses them to the uniques.

Which gives:

```
5, 2000
5, 3000
5, 4000
5, 5000
6, 2000
6, 7000
```

For the data, I'm using:

```
var collection = new[] { new {
        Id = 5,
        postalcodes = new[] { 2000, 3000, 4000}
    },
    new {
        Id = 5,
        postalcodes = new[] { 2000, 5000 }
    },
    new {
        Id = 6,
        postalcodes = new[] { 2000, 7000 }
    }};
```

Comment: That's what I tried so far, but I'm getting an error telling me there is an ambiguity with postalcode. I suspect it's because it is a nullable field, as I can select other properties without problems.

Comment: @Bv202 where are you getting that? what I have shown compiles and runs, so it would be great to see more context so we can help you with that

Answer (score 1):

you can use `SelectMany` to flattern inner collections, i.e.:

```
collection
.SelectMany(i => i.postalcodes.Select(j=>new{i.id, postalcode = j}))
.Distinct()
```

Comment: indeed, i've missed id duplication